# Webpack - не видно ошибку после сборки

Tags: vue.js, webpack, webpack-dev-server

Webpack 3.6.0. 
При сборке в dev-режиме, сборка завершается с ошибкой. При этом ошибку не показывает. Как увидеть ошибку?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сборка в prod-режиме завершается без ошибок

**П.С.:** хотя, я вот что понял - ошибку показывает, просто она `undefined`. Как же быть?

**П.С:** как посоветовали в комментарии - отключил весь проект от сборки (полностью закомментировал точку входа) - результат тот же. Получается конфликт модулей?

Comment: выкидывать по порядку из сборки куски. локализовать ошибку

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev, спасибо - так и сделал. Результат удивил - отключил весь проект, но ошибка осталась)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Выяснилось, что проблема была в отсутствии файла `index.html`, который используется для настроек `devServera` и всяких плагинов, типа `HtmlWebpackPlugin`.